# Square API: Payment notifications webhook returning wrong merchant id?

Tags: webhooks, square-connect

I have a webhook that my Square account is making requests to every time a `PAYMENT_UPDATED` event happens on an order. I'm following the API docs here: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#setupwebhooks

It says that the webhook makes a request to my app with these parameters:

```
{
  "merchant_id": "18YC4JBH91E1H",
  "location_id": "JGHJ0343",
  "event_type": "PAYMENT_UPDATED",
  "entity_id": "Jq74mCczmFXk1tC10GB"
}
```

This is the code in my node app:

index.js

```
app.post("/payment_notifications", (req, resp) => {
  paymentService.receivePayment(req.body, resp);
});
```

payment_service.js

```
module.exports = {
  receivePayment(requestBody, response){
    const { entity_id, location_id, merchant_id } = requestBody;
    console.log("payment_id: ", entity_id);
    console.log("location_id: ", location_id);
    console.log("merchant_id: ", merchant_id);
    console.dir("requestBody: ", requestBody);
    console.dir("requestBody.merchant_id: ", requestBody.merchant_id);
    console.dir("requestBody.location_id: ", requestBody.location_id);
    getPayment(entity_id, location_id, merchant_id);
    response.sendStatus(200);
  },
};
```

My app is printing the same value for `location_id` and `merchant_id` in the logs for each of the orders. I checked my database and that ID is a location ID, not a merchant ID

```
2016-11-07T17:28:55.770302+00:00 app[web.1]: payment_id: paymentId123123
2016-11-07T17:28:55.770328+00:00 app[web.1]: location_id: 6HB994C06J6PE
2016-11-07T17:28:55.770366+00:00 app[web.1]: merchant_id: 6HB994C06J6PE
```

What is going on?

Comment: In some cases a merchant Id and location Id could be the same, but that isn't likely looking at your case. Am I correct that you are working with a big multi location coffee shop?

Comment: Yes you are correct. From my logs it looks like all the location ids are the same as the merchant id

Comment: Gotcha. Did you recently update any of your webhooks configurations?

Comment: Might've switched the webhook on / off, but I don't believe I changed anything recently. Let me know if you need any more info

Comment: We are investigating. Location Ids should be more useful than merchant Ids for your application, is this causing you serious trouble?

Comment: Yes, Ideally I have the merchant id so that I can find the access token stored with the order's merchant, so that I can make another request and fetch more information about the order since all that is returned is the payment_id (entity_id)

Comment: Is this the proper way of fetching order info as they come in (storing the merchant access token in the backend and using that to fetch order info as they come in)? I have a few questions about this actually, but one thing at a time. No means to overwhelm you

Comment: In a situation like yours, generally yes, however there are a wide variety of ways to 'store in the back end' but it seems like you won't accidentally get them confused. If it helps, you can use the poorly documented `v1/{{location_id}}/business` endpoint to translate location ids into merchant ids.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, for most multi unit businesses webhook requests will only have the location id. We are working on upgrading our webhooks service to a v2 version and will fix this in the process.

In the meantime feel free to use the `v1/{{location_id}}/business` endpoint to get the correct merchant id from these notifications.